# Python for Nuke: Select node before current

Tags: python, nuke

How can I select a node via python before the one currently selected?

For example, I want to add a "Clamp" node exactly before all "Write" ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet allows you to define a node upstream existing Write node.

```
import nuke

iNode = nuke.toNode('Write1')

def upstream(iNode, maxDeep=-1, found=None):

    if found is None:
        found = set()
    if maxDeep != 0:
       willFind = set(z for z in iNode.dependencies() if z not in found)
       found.update(willFind)

       for depth in willFind:
           upstream(depth, maxDeep+1, found)

    return found
```

Then call the method `upstream(iNode)`.

And a script's snippet you've sent me earlier should look like this:

```
allWrites = nuke.allNodes('Grade')
depNodes = nuke.selectedNode().dependencies()

for depNode in depNodes:
    depNode.setSelected(True) 

queueElem = len(allWrites)
trigger = -1

for i in range(1,queueElem+1):
    trigger += 1

    for write in allWrites[(0+trigger):(1+trigger)]: 
        write.setSelected(True)
        nuke.createNode("Clamp")

        for all in nuke.allNodes():
            all.setSelected(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy! Thanks but not what I meant, sorry for the missunderstanding. What I really need is to select the node before the one I want. Imagine I have a bunch of "Write" nodes in my comp and I need to clamp them before writing, so I should select the node before the Write to add the Clamp one so it gets connected between both. I think it could be done via dependencies ()  or dependant ()  but not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: Hi @Andy, for some reason it's not working, Now I'm trying with this code:

`allWrites = nuke.allNodes('Write')
for write in allWrites:
    write.setSelected(True)
    for depNode in depNodes:
        depNode.setSelected(True)
        clampNode=nuke.createNode("Clamp")`  but it doesn't connect everything. Any further help please?

Comment: `allWrites = nuke.allNodes('Grade') 
for write in allWrites: 
    write.setSelected(True) 
    depNodes=nuke.selectedNode().dependencies()
    for depNode in depNodes: 
        depNode.setSelected(True)          
        clampNode=nuke.createNode("Clamp")`

Comment: Sorry for inconveniences but I can't execute the whole script 'cause I've got NUKE Non-Commercial version (There are only 10 nodes available in Python scripting using NC version). So I hope I've got enough ideas to compose your own script.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you)